# expiration date and google crawl errors

Tags: channel-entries

I have a site with an "Events" page.  Naturally, events come and go, and you don't want to see events from 2 years ago showing up on your site, so I have the admin person use the expiration date feature to have it no longer show on the website after the event has happened.  Recently I went onto the google webmaster tools for the site and saw that there were 404 crawl errors for the events that had expired.

Is this a problem, and if so, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation this is the expected (and desired) result.

You don't want old event entries showing up on the site so you set them to expire. When an expired entry's page is requested the default behavior is a 404 error (page not found). All Google Webmaster tools is confirming here is that it tried to crawl those expired pages and could not find them.

If you still want individual expired entries to be able to load, then in your `channel:entries` tag in your entry detail template you will need to set the [`show_expired`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-expired) parameter to "yes."

Comment: its functioning as desired.  I don't want old events to show up. I just wanted to make sure there's not an issue with these google crawl errors and if i can just mark them fixed and move on?

Comment: That's what I would do under those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a problem. The 404 is exactly what SHOULD be returned to Google. Over time Google will drop those URLs from its index.

In a way the "problem" is fixed since it's doing precisely what you want it to do but Google may report future 404s especially if you have that URL in a Google Site map file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do a redirect for expired events, on the same page when it expires, the page could redirect to the most recent event, altough , are you using Pages module ?